# Parsing Error while compiling pet-shop tutorial

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am just getting started with smart contract programming and was trying to implement the pet-shop example as per this tutorial https://medium.com/tomochain/how-to-build-a-dapp-on-tomochain-85532a1192e7. The contract code is as under

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Adoption {
  address[16] public adopters;
  // Adopting a pet
  function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
    // check that petId is in range of our adopters array
    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
    // add the address who called this function to our adopter array
    adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
    // return the petId provided as a confirmation
    return petId;
  }
  // Retrieving the adopters
  function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
    return adopters;
  }
}
```

compiler throws the following error:
*Error parsing /Users/Zubair/pet-shop-tutorial/contracts/Adoption.sol: ParsedContract.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf470
^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.3 (core: 5.0.3)
Node v10.15.1*

Comment: Maybe your file format isn't plain ascii. You might want to create it with a simple text editor.

Comment: ^ This is probably it. I remember [this question from some time ago which had the same problem](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65703/truffle-will-not-compile-contract-written-in-vs-code-pragma-error)

Comment: Thank you guys. That was the issue and its resolved now.